# xslt internationalization with php

Tags: php, xslt, internationalization

I use XSLT as template engine in my PHP framework. I set some text to Renderer script, which converts it to xml and pass to XSLTProcessor:

```
<?php
class IndexController extends ActionAbstract {
    public function doAuth() {
        $this->_Renderer->some_text = 'Translatable text';
    }
}
?>
```

View looks something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <head><title>Index.xsl</title></head>
            <body>
                Here is some text to be translated <br/>
                <xsl:value-of select="root/some_text"/>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

So, I have 2 types of text in views:

- Dynamic (setted from ActionController $this->_Renderer->some_text = 'Translatable text')
- Hardcoded in view (Here is some text to be translated)

I can use xml dictionary to translate Harcoded texts in xslt (using `document()` function), but how when translate texts setted from ActionController?

**What is the best way to translate texts in my views?**

UPDATE:
**Is it possible to print default value if no translate text was found?**

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way is to use xslt keys - you can find examples here: http://www.learn-xslt-tutorial.com/Working-with-Keys.cfm

In terms of your example it would look like (I didn't compiled it so maybe there's some typo or mistake):

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
        <xsl:output method="xml"/>
        <xsl:key name="keyDict" match="entry" use="key"/>
        <xsl:param name="text_to_translate2" select="root/some_text"/>

        <xsl:template match="/">
            <html>
                <head><title>Index.xsl</title></head>
                <body>
                    <!-- Here is some text to be translated -->
                    <xsl:value-of select="key('keyDict','text_to_translate1')/value"/> <br/>
                    <xsl:value-of select="key('keyDict',$text_to_translate2)/value"/>
                </body>
            </html>
        </xsl:template>

    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

And you'll need the xml's with a structure of:

```
    <entry>
        <key>text_to_transalte1</key>
        <value>some text1</value>
    </entry>
    <entry>
        ...
    </entry>
```

---

EDIT: For the default value just add  to entries in xml:

```
    <keyDict>
        <entry>
            <key>text_to_transalte1</key>
            <value>some text1</value>
        </entry>
        <entry>
            ...
        </entry>
        <default><value>No translation found</value></default>
    </keyDict>
```

Or in case you would like to make a default value for each key equal to the key (which is common I would say) then you can define new template:

```
    <xsl:template name="dictLookup">
        <xsl:param name="key"/>
        <xsl:variable name="result" select="key('keyDict',$key)/value"/>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="not($result)">
                <xsl:value-of select="$key"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:value-of select="$result"/>
            <xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>
```

and then call this template with param:

```
    <xsl:call-template name="dictLookup">
        <xsl:with-param name="key" value="some value"/>
    </xsl:call-template>
```

You could even add another parameter, named default to call the tamplate as follows:

```
    <xsl:call-template name="dictLookup">
        <xsl:with-param name="key" value="some value"/>
        <xsl:with-param name="default" value="default value"/>
    </xsl:call-template>
```

I hope this answers your question

Comment: Thanks a lot! This works amazingly, but is it possible to somehow reduce the ammount of typing :) every time i have to write 3 lines of code just to output some words

Comment: Well, don't have a good answer for that - you could shrink it to one line though: `<xsl:call-template name="dictLookup"><xsl:with-param name="key" value="some value"/></xsl:call-template>` :P